# Companion Lecture Notes to Atiyah-MacDonald?

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

Is there a set of lecture notes that follow Atiyah-MacDonald and expand on the dense passages, point out typos and so forth?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try the following A. Altman and S. Kleiman: A term of commutative algebra, 2012. 
You can read it for free here:
http://web.mit.edu/18.705/www/12Nts.pdf

Comment: WOW,these notes look terrific and exactly what the OP was looking for. I'm currently researching and compiling a list of free mathematics sources on the Web-I'm really glad you called attention to this jewel or I'd have missed it,Oliver!

Comment: Updated version: http://web.mit.edu/18.705/www/

Comment: Even more up-to-date: [2021 version](https://web.archive.org/web/20210703201703/https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Steven-Kleiman/publication/351211952_A_Term_of_Commutative_Algebra/links/608b6380458515d315e6bc21/A-Term-of-Commutative-Algebra.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Here are two links where you can find further links to downloads such as you are looking for:

http://math.berkeley.edu/~aboocher/research.html

http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Courses.html

I myself was/am in the market for these. In passing I saw a mention of this book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Commutative-Algebra-Mathematical-Society-Student/dp/0521646235](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521646235)

I have not looked at it, but it might be useful. The author is actually acknowledged in the preface to "A&M."

Answer (score 2):

(Sorry, this post should really be a comment to the [answer by Oliver E. Anderson](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/293831/894270), but I don't have enough reputation to be able to comment yet. Please someone re-post it as a comment instead of me. If you notify me, I'll delete this answer.)

The latest revision of the textbook by Altman and Kleiman can be found at [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/385313/175094). Be sure to get at least the 2017 version or newer, which was a substantial expansion.